# Axios Post with formData does not work with Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

I'm using Axios v0.27.1 for ajax, but does not work to post the files and data to Laravel Controller. When I use `$request->all()` in controller. It will return a blank `[]` array. Any ideas for this case?

```
$('#submitForm7').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#form7Excel').prop('files')[0]);
    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
        , responseType: 'blob'
    }
    axios
        .post('/pdf/generateForm7', formData, config)
        .then(resp => {
            //success callback
            if (resp.status == 200) {
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
        })
        .finally(() => {})
})
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with special attention on the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score -1):

Can access file using

> $request->file('file');

and your all Request data (without file data) You can access using

> $request->all();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Smit Butani, i have tried to use those coding, but it seems also blank. I think there is some wrong between chrome and Axios. It works now this morning (I don't change any coding). Btw Great Thanks